# How to print if answer is correct or incorrect in list then add to score

Tags: python

New to programming and not sure how to print if the users answer to the list questions is correct or not and then add it to their ongoing score which will be displayed at the end of the program.

```
#number list test program

import random
import statistics 
choosequestion = random.randint(1,4)

print('Welcome to the number list test')

print('e) Easy')
print('m) Medium')
print('h) Hard')
difficulty = input('Difficulty: ')

if difficulty == 'e':
    print('Easy difficulty selected')

    score = 0
    questions = 2
    quantity = 3
    minimum = 1
    maximum = 5
    lists = random.sample(range(minimum, maximum), quantity)

if choosequestion == 1:
          print ('What is the smallest number in this list?', lists)
          finalmin = min = int(input(""))
elif choosequestion == 2:
          print ('What is the biggest number in this list?', lists)
          finalmax = max = int(input(""))
elif choosequestion == 3:
          print ('What is the sum of numbers in this list?', lists)
          finalsum = sum = int(input(""))
elif choosequestion == 4:
          print ('What is the average of the numbers in this list?', lists)
          average = statistics.mean = int(input(""))

##elif difficulty == 'm':
##    print('Medium difficulty selected')
##    
##elif difficulty == 'h':
##    print ('Medium difficulty selected')
```

Any help will be great, thanks (when running the program select 'e' to start, I've commented out all other options)

Comment: Hi @Will can you please elaborate on what exactly you need?

Comment: And please try to work out a working [mre]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use for loops to ask questions repetitively.
2. As user enters answer, calculate the real answer in program and compare the result, to score.

You can refer below code.

```py
#number list test program

import random
import statistics 
choosequestion = random.randint(1,4)

print('Welcome to the number list test')

print('e) Easy')
print('m) Medium')
print('h) Hard')
difficulty = input('Difficulty: ')

if difficulty == 'e':
    print('Easy difficulty selected')

    score = 0
    questions = 2
    quantity = 3
    minimum = 1
    maximum = 5
    for i in range(0,questions):
        lists = random.sample(range(minimum, maximum), quantity)
        if choosequestion == 1:
            print ('What is the smallest number in this list?', lists)
            if int(input(""))==min(lists):
                score+=1
                print("Correct answer")
            else:
                print("Wrong answer")
        elif choosequestion == 2:
            print ('What is the biggest number in this list?', lists)
            if int(input(""))==max(lists):
                score+=1
                print("Correct answer")
            else:
                print("Wrong answer")
        elif choosequestion == 3:
            print ('What is the sum of numbers in this list?', lists)
            if int(input(""))==sum(lists):
                score+=1
                print("Correct answer")
            else:
                print("Wrong answer")
        elif choosequestion == 4:
            print ('What is the average of the numbers in this list?', lists)
            if int(input(""))==sum(lists)/len(lists):
                score+=1
                print("Correct answer")
            else:
                print("Wrong answer")

print("Your final score is : "+str(score))
```

Answer (score 0):

The input() function in python returns a string of what the user types in a console. You can then compare the input string with the correct answer with an equal operator ==. (True if it matches, of course) I've finished a couple lines of code to demonstrate:

```
      #Ask the User the Question
      print ('What is the smallest number in this list?', lists)

      #Get the User's response
      userAnswer = int(input(""))
      
      #Compare the response with the right answer
      if(userAnswer == min(lists)):
        #User was right
        print("Correct")
        score += 1
      else:
        #User was wrong
        print("Wrong")
```

Change the min() function to max(), sum(), or your own function to get the right answer for each question.

For the future, many things could help improve this code:

1. Comment your code to give a main idea of what it is doing. I'm not talking one comment for each line, just a summary of sections of code.
2. When using an user input in any language, make sure to stress test it. The int(input("")) crashes the program when the user inputs a string.
3. Take advantage of functions, loops, and variables. I've seen programmers go down the rabbit hole of using if else statements too much. Do not avoid if else statements necessarily, but use patterns in answers and code to your advantage.